# Error 404 while loading images in drupal

Tags: image, drupal, http-status-code-404

My Server's PHP has updated to version 5.3 recently. After this upgrade the drupal which is installed on my site doesn't load the pictures which are located in the '/sites/default/files/' directory. It throws 404 error for every picture stored in this path.
I am pretty confused with this. Do I have to make any change to my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible directory permissions were changed when php was upgraded? That would be the simplest explanation, since I'm not aware of a reason why php 5.3 would itself cause this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was another .htaccess file in my 'sites/default/files/' folder. My web hosting company has obligated me to remove FollowSymLink. But I didn't know that there was another .htaccess file in my drupal folder. I removed that and now everything is working smoothly.